# Getting a 401 Error when using Twitter API User/Search

Tags: c#, twitter, windows-runtime, twitter-oauth

I have an application which allows the user to authorise my application in order for it to use Twitters REST Api. This process works fine however when I try to perform GET request to search for hash tags it all falls apart. The documentation i am using is the following https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/search/tweets

So first up I checked my *Signature Base* against Twitter's Generate one.

**Mine**

```
GET&https%3A%2F%2Fapi.twitter.com%2F1.1%2Fsearch%2Ftweets.json&oauth_consumer_key%3Dik7trnFwjZ1aoQBajjLv9A%26oauth_nonce%3D500199554%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1%26oauth_timestamp%3D1360688610%26oauth_token%3D932308590-5KAmpqMDIOC9tcrhVSfwCxMz0ye8BXmhKSQyPb97%26oauth_version%3D1.0%26q%3D%2523ireland
```

**Twitter**

```
GET&https%3A%2F%2Fapi.twitter.com%2F1.1%2Fsearch%2Ftweets.json&oauth_consumer_key%3Dik7trnFwjZ1aoQBajjLv9A%26oauth_nonce%3D8522ba23a34a6748d7bd6e2e5b68c56f%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1%26oauth_timestamp%3D1360681312%26oauth_token%3D932308590-5KAmpqMDIOC9tcrhVSfwCxMz0ye8BXmhKSQyPb97%26oauth_version%3D1.0%26q%3D%2523ireland
```

Those seem reasonably similar with the only difference being the generated nonce (not sure if that is problem). Now the one thing which I find strange in this is that the request is

```
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=%23ireland
```

But from looking at the signature base from Twitters OAuth tool I have to remove the ? from that request when generating the Signuatre Base which seems strange.

Next is my *Authorization Headers*

**Mine**

```
Authorization: OAuth oauth_consumer_key="ik7trnFwjZ1aoQBajjLv9A", oauth_nonce="500199554", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_timestamp="1360688610", oauth_token="932308590-5KAmpqMDIOC9tcrhVSfwCxMz0ye8BXmhKSQyPb97", oauth_version="1.0", oauth_signature="aSytUd6HrwAzzAzDyP%2FMqL2qNCE%3D"
```

**Twitter**

```
Authorization: OAuth oauth_consumer_key="ik7trnFwjZ1aoQBajjLv9A", oauth_nonce="8522ba23a34a6748d7bd6e2e5b68c56f", oauth_signature="bw0My7Z3ESXDOjsTLYgbTIjGi6s%3D", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_timestamp="1360681312", oauth_token="932308590-5KAmpqMDIOC9tcrhVSfwCxMz0ye8BXmhKSQyPb97", oauth_version="1.0"
```

The only difference in this is that the order of my Signature is different however I havent see any documentation which says it must match up perfectly.

So finally I set up my actual request which is simply

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            request.Method = "GET";
            request.Headers["Authorization"] = headers;
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)await request.GetResponseAsync();
```

Where the URL is the URL mentioned above. When my method runs I get a 401 response

```
[System.Net.WebException] = {"The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized."}
```

Anyone spot anything wrong in my implementation or something I may have missed out on?

Comment: Same problem here. All other 1.1 endpoints work without problems for me but not the search endpoint. Am absolutely clueless.

Answer (score 0):

For your Authorization Headers, I read you should have them in alphabetical order. Your oauth_version and oauth_signature are in a different order than twitters.